# Quickest way to populate a select list with options from another select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectlist

I have a select list of options. I want to instantly make another select list contain the same options.

```
$('#list1 option').appendTo('#list2');
```

The idea above is right, but for some reason it removes all the options from the original list which I dont want to do!
Can anyone help with this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just missing a `.clone()`:

```
$('#select1 option').clone().appendTo($('#select2').empty());
```

If `#select2` is already empty, then you can simply `.appendTo('#select2')`.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you can manipulate lists easily...

```
$().ready(function() {
$('#add').click(function() {
return !$('#select1 option:selected').appendTo('#select2');
});
$('#remove').click(function() {
return !$('#select2 option:selected').appendTo('#select1');
});
});
```

"If you click the “add” button, we remove the selected option from select1 and add that same option to select2"  - Example from http://calisza.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/6-jquery-snippets-you-can-use-to-manipulate-select-inputs/